# SQLAlchemy / pyODBC not releasing database connection

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I'm using SQLAlchemy (Core only, not ORM) to create a connection to a SQL Server 2008 SP3.

When looking at the process' network connections, I noticed that the TCP/IP connection to the SQL Server (port 1433) remains open (`ESTABLISHED`).

Sample code:

```
from urllib.parse import quote_plus
from sqlalchemy.pool import NullPool
import sqlalchemy as sa

# parameters are read from a config file
db_params = quote_plus(';'.join(['{}={}'.format(key, val) for key, val in db_config.items()]))
# Hostname based connection
engine = sa.create_engine('mssql:///?odbc_connect={}'.format(db_params), 
                          poolclass=NullPool)

conn = engine.connect()
conn.close()

engine.dispose()
engine = None
```

I added the `NullPool` and the `engine.dispose()` afterwards, thinking they might solve the lingering connection, but alas.

I'm using as hostname based connection as specified [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/dialects/mssql.html#hostname-connections).

Versions:

- Python 3.5.0 (x32 on Win7)
- SQLAlchemy 1.0.10
- pyODBC 3.0.10

---

**Edit**: I've rewritten my code to solely use pyODBC instead of SQLAlchemy + pyODBC, and the issue remains. So as far as I can see, the issue is caused by pyODBC keeping the connection open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When only pyODBC, the *issue* is because of connection pooling as discussed [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pyodbc/Mg6rFPb4gw8).

As described in the [docs](https://mkleehammer.github.io/pyodbc/api.html):

> **pooling**
>
> A Boolean indicating whether connection pooling is enabled.
> This is a global (HENV) setting, so it can only be modified before the
> first connection is made. The default is True, which enables ODBC
> connection pooling.

Thus:

```
import pyodbc

pyodbc.pooling = False 
conn = pyodbc.connect(db_connection_string) 
conn.close()
```

It seems that when using SQLAlchemy and disabling the SA pooling by using the `NullPool`, this isn't passed down to pyODBC.